# python loop array

Tags: python, arrays, loops

```
arr = [(line.rstrip('\n').split(';')) for line in open('C:/Config_Changer.csv')]
import sys
import fileinput
for i, line in enumerate(fileinput.input('C:/1.cfg', inplace = 1)):
    sys.stdout.write(line.replace(arr[0][0], arr[0][1]))
```

Hey all,

I wrote the above lines so it's working fine but its replacing only ary[0][0], so i want to loop it as like below,so first dimention is needed to loop.Can anyone help me with the loop commands.Where should I have to put loop exactly ???

```
sys.stdout.write(line.replace(arr[a][0], arr[a][1]))
```

Comment: Please explain in more detail what are you trying to achieve, why you're having problems and what you have tried!

Comment: ok I have an multidimentional array i want to replace values that I gather from multidimentional array and put into file that I opened at line 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so what you want is to apply all the replacements that are in `arr` to the `line`: (unlike aix's answer, this one avoids the explicit indexing)

```
for i, line in enumerate(fileinput.input('C:/1.cfg', inplace = 1)):
    for f,t in arr:
        line = line.replace(f, t)
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided I am understanding your requirements correctly:

```
for i, line in enumerate(fileinput.input('C:/1.cfg', inplace = 1)):
    for j in xrange(len(arr)):
        line = line.replace(arr[j][0], arr[j][1])
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

or -- perhaps more Pythonically --

```
for i, line in enumerate(fileinput.input('C:/1.cfg', inplace = 1)):
    for repl in arr:
        line = line.replace(repl[0], repl[1])
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```